# How to enable the button in the template field when there is an uploaded file in another template field

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a three TemplateFields in this gridview. First templatefield will contain the path of the file, second is the "upload" button template field and the last is the "release" button templatefield where when clicked, it will generate the date today in the boundfield in the same gridview. The condition is the user needs to upload a pdf file before the button "release" in the templatefield will be enable because the default is disable.

**the HTML code is this:**

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CFVGL" SortExpression="cfvgl_path" ControlStyle-ForeColor="Blue" ItemStyle-Width="">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="link1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("cfvgl_path")%>' 
                        NavigateUrl='<%# "~/"+"CFVGL/" + Eval("cfvgl_path") %>' Target="_blank"  ></asp:HyperLink>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <ControlStyle ForeColor="Blue"></ControlStyle>
                <HeaderStyle CssClass="tblheader2" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Upload File" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign ="center"  >
                <ItemTemplate> 
                    <table id="colWith">
                    <tr>
                        <td><asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload4" runat="server" Width="180px"></asp:FileUpload></td>
                        <td><asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" EnableViewState="False" Text="Upload" CommandName="Upload"  
                          CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>'
                          OnClick="saveTheFile"></asp:Button ></td>
                    </tr>
                    </table></ItemTemplate>
                <HeaderStyle CssClass ="tblheader2" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate> 
                    <asp:Button ID="release" runat="server" EnableViewState="False" Text="Release" CommandName="Upload"  
                          CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>'
                          OnClick="dateReleased_Click" Enabled="False"></asp:Button >
                </ItemTemplate>
                <HeaderStyle CssClass ="tblheader2" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

**The VB code of GridView1_RowDataBound:**

```
   Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim status As Integer = e.Row.Cells(2).Text
        Select Case status
            Case 0
                e.Row.Cells(2).Text = "for submission of requirements"
            Case 1
                e.Row.Cells(2).Text = "for compliance of lacking requirements"
            Case 2
                e.Row.Cells(2).Text = "for evaluation"
            Case 3
                e.Row.Cells(2).Text = "for signature"
            Case 4
                e.Row.Cells(2).Text = "approved and ready for release"
            Case 7
                e.Row.Cells(2).Text = "released"
        End Select
    End If
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

        Dim release As Button = CType(e.Row.FindControl("release"), Button)
        If release IsNot Nothing AndAlso Uploaded = True Then
            release.Attributes.Remove("enable")
            release.Attributes.Add("disable", "disable")
        Else
            release.Attributes.Remove("disable")
            release.Attributes.Add("enable", "enable")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

**Here is the VB code for saveTheFile**

```
Protected Sub saveTheFile(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    Dim gvr As GridViewRow = DirectCast(btn.NamingContainer, GridViewRow)
    'Get rowindex
    Dim rowindex As Integer = gvr.RowIndex
    '------------------------------------------------------------
    Dim fileUploadRowControl As FileUpload = DirectCast(gvr.FindControl("fileUpload4"), FileUpload)
    ' to view fileupload inside the gridview
    If fileUploadRowControl Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox("No file uploaded.")
    Else
        Dim savePath As String = Path.GetFileName(fileUploadRowControl.PostedFile.FileName)
        fileUploadRowControl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~\\CFVGL\\" & savePath))
        '
        Dim ext As String = Path.GetExtension(savePath)
        Dim contenttype As String = String.Empty
        Dim fileName As String = fileUploadRowControl.FileName
        If fileUploadRowControl.PostedFile Is Nothing OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(fileUploadRowControl.PostedFile.FileName) OrElse fileUploadRowControl.PostedFile.InputStream Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox("Unable to upload the file.")
        End If
        'Set the contenttype based on File Extension
        Select Case ext
            Case ".pdf"
                contenttype = "application/pdf"
                Exit Select
        End Select
        If contenttype <> String.Empty Then
            Dim fs As Stream = fileUploadRowControl.PostedFile.InputStream
            Dim br As New BinaryReader(fs)
            Dim bytes As Byte() = br.ReadBytes(fs.Length)
            'InsertItemPosition file to database
            Dim StrQuery As String = ("Update cfvgl set cfvgl_path= @Cfvgl_path where v_id =@id")
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(StrQuery)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Cfvgl_path", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = savePath
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = gvr.Cells(0).Text
            InsertUpdateData(cmd)
            MsgBox("File Uploaded Successfully!")
        Else
            MsgBox("File format not recognized." _
            & " Please Upload PDF formats")
        End If
    End If
    Dim row As GridViewRow = sender.NamingContainer
    Dim FileUpload4 As FileUpload = DirectCast(row.FindControl("FileUpload4"), FileUpload)
    Dim release As Button = DirectCast(row.FindControl("release"), Button)
    If FileUpload4.HasFile Then
        release.Enabled = True
    Else
        release.Enabled = False
    End If End Sub
```

My problem is the code in vb was not working to enable the release button. Any solution please? Thanks.

Comment: are you binding the GridView at PageLoad, if so, are you binding it inside `If Not IsPostBack`

Answer (score 0):

The button `btnUpload` is posting the form. So, GridView's `RowDatabound` is not the right place for enabling or disabling the `release` button. Clicking `btnUpload` will trigger the `saveTheFile` method, you have to place code there. Your code should look like this:

```
Protected Sub saveTheFile(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim row As GridViewRow = sender.NamingContainer
    Dim FileUpload4 As FileUpload = DirectCast(row.FindControl("FileUpload4"), FileUpload)
    Dim release As Button = DirectCast(row.FindControl("release"), Button)

    If FileUpload4.HasFile Then
        release.Enabled = True
    Else
        release.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Hope it helps!

**EDIT :**

In your code **change** this part:

```
If fileUploadRowControl Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox("No file uploaded.")
Else
... ... ...
```

To this:

```
Dim release As Button = DirectCast(gvr.FindControl("release"), Button)

If Not fileUploadRowControl.HasFile Then
        'MsgBox("No file uploaded.")'Don't use MsgBox
        release.Enabled = False
Else
        release.Enabled = True
        'Do other task
```

Comment: Hi @afzalulh
I already consolidated the code you had suggested but it wasn't still functioning. I uploaded a pdf file yet the release button was still disable.

Answer (score 0):

In your global declarations within your class file

```
    Dim Uploaded  As Boolean=False
```

Then

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound

 If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

         Dim release As button = CType(e.Row.FindControl("release"), Button)
            If release IsNot Nothing AndAlso  Uploaded=True Then
            realese.Attributes.remove('enabled')
            release.Attributes.Add("disabled","disabled")
        Else
             release.Attributes.remove('disabled')
             release.Attributes.Add("enabled","enabled")
        End If
   End if 
 End Sub
```

Uploaded is a global variable you can set to true when your upload is successful in your save the file method.

```
Protected Sub saveTheFile(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim row As GridViewRow = sender.NamingContainer
    Dim FileUpload4 As FileUpload = DirectCast(row.FindControl("FileUpload4"), FileUpload)
    If FileUpload4.HasFile Then
        Uploaded = True
   End If
    GridView1.DataBind() 'so that row databound is fired
End Sub
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: In your GridView1_RowDataBound event. I  am going to update my answer

Comment: I had tried the code but the variable "uploaded" was not recognized. It says that I should declare it first.

Comment: Declare it outside you methods as a global variable.Dim Uploaded as Bolean=false.Then set it to true in your save method.i have removed the double quotes on the word true for it to be a boolean..

Comment: Hi again @Abide Masaraure.

I incorporated the codes you had suggested yet still, it wasn't working. I had edited my question above and posted the codes for you to see. Thanks.

Comment: I have updated my answer.The variable Uploaded still needs to be set in your code like I have done now.